# How can I direct all network traffic on my devices to 127.0.0.1 with a specified local port on an ssh that I setup on a separate android using termux?

Tags: ssh, proxy

So far, I have only been able to do the following steps:

Install openssh on termux.

```
pkg install openssh
```

Then I turned on hotspot on my phone.

Then I found the phone's IP address using `ifconfig` which was `192.168.126.176` and user name by `whoami` which was `u0_a195` on termux.

I setup the password on termux by typing `passwd`.

Then I ran `sshd -dD` on termux.

Then I connected my Windows 10 PC WiFi to the hotspot and opened CMD.

```
ssh -D 8123 -fqgN u0_a195@192.168.126.176 -p 8022
```

I typed up the password that I already setup to ssh in.

From here nothing else happens on the CMD

In termux, it said `accepted password for u0_a195 from 192.168.126.69 port 60353 ssh2`

Then I go to settings on windows10 global proxy settings and select manual proxy.
I set it up as `127.0.0.1:8123`

I then tried to connect to the internet on the PC but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Network troubleshooting goes in steps. First do `ping 1.1.1.1` from Termux. Then login to `ssh` shell from Windows and `ping` again. If both work then problem is on your Windows side.

Comment: SSH port forwarding is for forwarding TCP connection(s). A forwarded TCP connection is not a proxy. You need to install and run a proxy on your phone, otherwise you can't use it as proxy. An HTTP proxy uses special commands that only a proxy understands, therefore you can not simply format a TCP connection. Please see also this very similar question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234655/2241

Comment: thank you I got it to work by setting up a shadowsocks server on my phone and connecting to that server from my PC and setting the PC's global proxy to localhost:(shadowsocks port).